# Emscripten code for image data download using emscripten_wget or emscripten_async_wget

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

I'm writting a web app that has to execute some c code so I went for emscripten. The workflow I need is the following:

1. Download an image from a server and save it's data into the File System.
2. Call some c functions to do some processing.
3. Call some WebCrypto API functions to decrypt info.
4. Call again some other c functions to do some processing.
5. Show the result in the browser.

As it involves a lot of Javascript and C mixing I have no idea how to handle the run loop, the async, etc as I'm completely new to emscripten.
My thoughts are using emscripten_wget for the first points and save it using a FS of type MEMFS. The problem I have is loading the image synchronously.

So, in my php file I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="a.out.js"></script>
<script>
P3Func = Module.cwrap('p3stuff', 'number', ['string', 'string']);
P3Func("<?php echo($imgurl); ?>", "<?php echo($wrappedkey); ?>");
</script>
```

And in my c file I have this:

```
int p3stuff(char *imgUrl, unsigned char *wrappedkey)
{    
// create a directory "working" in the virtual file system and mount it to the current Posix file system.
    EM_ASM(
      FS.mkdir('/working');
      FS.mount(MEMFS, {}, '/working');
    );

  char *path = "/working/myImage.jpg";

  printf("Downloading...\n");

  //Download image and save it to the File System
  emscripten_wget(imgUrl, path);

  printf("Download completed\n");

  FILE *img;
  img=fopen(path,"r");
  if(img==NULL) {
      printf("ERROR: Can't open file!\n");
      exit (2);
  }
}
```

Actually I get a weird behavior: with a wrappedkey param lenght of 24 characters I get the image downloaded and read properly and if the lenght is instead 22 I get the can't open file error wich for me it doesn't make any sense:

```
exit(2) called, but noExitRuntime, so halting execution but not exiting the runtime or preventing further async execution (you can use emscripten_force_exit, if you want to force a true shutdown)
```

And then:

```
still waiting on run dependencies:
a.out.js:139 dependency: cp /working/myImage.jpg
a.out.js:139 (end of list)
```

repeated many times.

Comment: Did you build with `-s ASYNCIFY=1`? `emscripten_wget` requires it.

Comment: Sure, I'm building with ASYNCIFY=1